# Deactivate a plugin on wp version

Tags: php, functions, theme-options, deactivation

I've creating a theme options page at the moment and was playing around with this function `deactivate_plugins()` I'm running wordpress 3.8.3 so running this code in my plugin should uninstall it.

Questions

1.Am I using this function incorrectly?
 2. Because the version 4.0 of Wordpress doesn't exist does the logic not work?

```
 register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'dw_deactivate_theme_options' ); // activate hook

    function dw_deactivate_theme_options() {
        if ( version_compare( get_bloginfo('version'), '4.0', '<') )  { // check the version
            deactivate_plugins( basename( __FILE__ ) ); // deactivate this plugin if the version is lower then 3.8
        }
    }
```

Full plugin code

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Theme Settings
Plugin URI: xxx
Description: This Plugin will generate all of the theme options, Social Media, Logo, Google analytics.
Version: 0.0.1
Author: xxx
Author URI: xxx
License: GPL2
*/

/*
Function Reference 
plugins_url() - Full plugins directory URL (for example,http://example.com/wp - content/plugins )
register_activation_hook(); Hook to add settings before plugin activation 2nd parem is callback function


*/

//Preset plugin functions

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'dw_deactivate_theme_options' ); // activate hook

function dw_deactivate_theme_options() {
    if ( version_compare( get_bloginfo('version'), '4.0', '<') )  { // check the version
        deactivate_plugins( basename( __FILE__ ) ); // deactivate this plugin if the version is lower then 3.8
    }
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'dw_theme_options_create_menu');

function dw_theme_options_create_menu() {
    //create custom top-level menu
    add_menu_page('Theme Options', 'Theme Settings', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'dw_theme_options_cb');
}

function dw_theme_options_cb() {
    echo '<img src"' .plugins_url( 'img/theme_icon.png', __FILE__ ) . '">'; // ?>
        <h2>Theme Settings</h2>
    <?php echo get_bloginfo('version'); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is **not** `version_compare`, the problem is that `register_activation_hook` is just a shortcut for

```
add_action( 'activate_' . $file, $function );
```

where `$file` is `plugin_basename( __FILE__ );` and `__FILE__` is your main plugin file absolute path.

So, what your code does is to call `dw_deactivate_theme_options()` when the action `'activate_' . $plugin` is fired.

But this action is fired *before* the plugin is activated i.e. before the plugin is added to the option `'active_plugins'`.

In short you are trying to deactivate a plugin that is not yet active and so your function does nothing.

There are 2 easy ways to avoid a plugin is activated under some conditions inside the function registered with `register_activation_hook`:

1. the first is do a redirect:

   ```
   function dw_deactivate_theme_options() {
     if ( version_compare( get_bloginfo('version'), '4.0', '<') )  {
       global $status, $paged, $s;
       $url = self_admin_url( "plugins.php?plugin_status=$status&paged=$page&s=$s" );
       wp_redirect( $url );
       exit();
     }
   }
   ```

   this works, but users just see the page being reloaded and plugin not activated, but without any error message... it's not very intuitive
2. the second, probably better, way is `die` inside the function, in this way the plugin is not activated and you can give a feedback to users putting a message into `die` function:

   ```
   function dw_deactivate_theme_options() {
     if ( version_compare( get_bloginfo('version'), '4.0', '<') )  {
       $message = "Impossible activate Theme Settings plugin because ";
       $message .= "WordPress version is lower than 4.0";
       die( $message );
     }
   }
   ```

   In this way plugin is not activated and users see a message, even if WordPress will say that your plugin triggered a fatal error..

[image: Check WP version before activate a plugin, and trigger error if check fail]